# How to use Lwuit Resource Editor for Creating Theme or GUI?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, midp-2.0, lwuit-resource-editor

I am just downloaded lwuit resource editor. I trying to create theme but i don't have idea how to create theme or gui. Can any one give me information how to use it? How to create gui or theme? And also i have one question how to use the created theme in netbean for j2me application. Please help me friends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lot of video's available on the [Shai's blog.](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2011/02/lwuit-resource-editor-developers.html) Here you can know about how to use latest LWUIT ResourceEdit. Current version of LWUIT ResourceEdit is little bit differnet from old ResourceEdit. Some few tools added into new LWUIT ResourceEdit like GUI, Multi images. After creating the GUI you can directly generate the class file or project to Netbeans.