# Using GUI based java application for mobile application

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, java-me, mobile-application

I have developed a java application in Netbeans 7.1.2 that uses different swing controls like combobox, jcalendar (for taking date input from user) textfields (for inputs from user), command button for doing calculation in code etc. and finally display result in textfield. The program also uses a derby data table while doing calculations. Using SQL statements i am executing some queries based on user input. The application works absolutely fine.

Now, I want to make a standalone mobile application of this project. Considering the controls that i am using above what is the appropriate source package and file that I should be looking for in the mobile application project? I don't mind building the GUI again and putting the code in it as its not much of a work but if I can use the already built application as it is then its well and good.

After a bit of google, I have tried opening a mobile application in Java ME and open a JAVA Package (right click>New>Java Package), here I tried with (right click>New>) Visual MIDlet, JFrame Form, A GUI Xlet form etc. But none of them seem to have swing controls. The pallette shows beans, java persistence and jcalendar only.

Am I supposed to add/load controls from some jar file? or Does the mobile application not support swing controls? in such a case how can I generate my GUI using something else/similar? I have tried copy pasting from my earlier form design into a new JFrame form but the source code is red all over and errors like `java.awt.event.actionEvent does not exist` are appearing on all controls in the code. Am I supposed to import something here?

The application is meant for both, smart phones with full wide touch screens and simple phones with small screens where I may have to change the interface by breaking it into smaller bits for taking user input one by one and loading them one after another. But right now I want some suggestions for the full GUI for widescreen smart-phones.

The reason I am using JAVA ME is because I feel then it can be deployed on any phone irrespective of its OS. Please correct me if I am wrong and enlighten me.

Comment: Have you seen this other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610677/how-to-use-lwuit-resource-editor-for-creating-theme-or-gui

Comment: Its a completely new domain you have opened for me. Thanks. I will look into it and revert. it seems LWUIT does not work on BlackBerry as yet. I am also concerned about data table although it has one. let me study it first. Thanks again.

Comment: your applications is on BlackBerry ?

Comment: Lucifer, I would like it to be for all phones including bb.

Answer (score 0):

The j2me is subset of java. It contains some of the java packages, classes, etc. It does not contain some the classes, packages of java. It also contains some additional j2me specific classes,packages,etc which are not in java.

The j2me specific packages contains some classes for gui which is similar to AWT, Swing, etc.

Better you first read any j2me tutorial for sample programs. Then it will helpful to build a project.

"J2ME complete reference" is good book for beginners.